# Spring Cloud Stream dynamic sink listeners

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am starting to use SCS and I have the following use case:

1. A user opens an HTTP session
2. The server dynamically figures out which partition to create a sink listener to, based on user security attributes
3. A Sink/Listener is created, specific for the user session, and attached to the channel partition.
4. Messages are forwarded via an http websocket to a browser client.
5. When the user logs off, the listener on the channel must be destroyed.

Reading the reference documentation shows no whay for such dynamic configuration and life-cycle management. Any clue on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking onto this.

Right now I can create dynamic producers using [BinderAwareChannelResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binding/BinderAwareChannelResolver.html). But Unfortunately I haven't found anything on the dynamic consumers.